# Would anybody like to critique my portfolio?

Tags: critique, portfolio, review, improvement

so I'm a bit lost right now to be honest. I took a long hiatus from design generally, due to personal reasons/burn out.

However, I find myself drawn back to it, for different reasons. I have a portfolio of work, but I don't send it out to clients anymore, and when I have it hasn't got much responses.

I'm under no illusion that this is great. But I would like some pointers on the work shown, what you like what you don't like?

1. Areas to improve.
2. Good points.
3. Any resources to look at.

[image: logo development #1 : baby-bright - initial idea(s)]

[image: logo development #2 : baby-bright - coloured variations]

[image: logo development #3 : selection and finesse]

[image: mock-ups with logo/visual style]

Comment: Hey Ashley. Check out our [requirements for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) and please edit your post to fit those requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I hope  you're doing well 
I m a complete graphic design  newbie with no Portfolio yet.
But i can tell thay what you're showing above is not a Portfolio.  It looks more like a  "confusing" process .

Portfolio should contain your best work, if you don't have many then at least put in one complete project.

Someone asked for my portfolio last day and i don't have it. And since i don't have much time to build a perfect one, i m planning to send him one project with : 
- logo + brand identify  & stationary in mockups 
- landing page template + social media visuals

I think you can start it from beginning.